# Overwritten partition recovery

Tags: data-recovery, testdisk, data-loss

I installed a fresh new ubuntu over the old one on the same partition, then realized that i have not pushed one month progress of coding up to GitHub branch (locally committed).

I heard about [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and gave it a try, all old partitions says when I try to list there files corrupted system files.

I want to know if I have luck to restore my branches using any suggested tools

Comment: So what was the result of running Testdisk ?

Comment: @SorenA cannot list files corrupted system files

Comment: If testdisk can't find any old files, and you don't have a backup .. I think that you are out of luck.